# How to customize share intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have a share button already integrated to my app but instead of sharing the link (I am using Webview) instead I want to share a custom text for example "To get more facts download the APPNAME from the android store PLAYSTORELINK"

```
    private void sharePost() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_chooser_method)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that by "share button" you mean `ShareActionProvider` or something else that uses an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, adjust your `EXTRA_TEXT` value to be what you want. Beyond that, we cannot help you without seeing your code for your "share button".

Comment: I have edited the post with my code! sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mUri);
```

with:

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "To get more facts download the APPNAME from the android store PLAYSTORELINK");
```